# Grabbing certain text from a string in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I'm currently starting to script more in Python and could use some help! I have a function that returns some stats from a server. Currently my function:

```
def get_free_memory(ssh_obj):
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_obj.exec_command('free -h')
mem_stats = stdout.readlines()[1]
mem_stats_formatted = " ".join(mem_stats.split())
return mem_stats_formatted
```

returns

```
Mem: 991M 71M 757M 12M 162M 751M
```

I'd like to further parse useful info from this output and get the total memory (991M) and the available memory (757M). What would be the best way to do this?

Also would it be better to return both or have two separate functions. One called get_free_memory and get_available_memory?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you also show us a sample input?

Comment: You seem to already know `split()` - what are you asking exactly? (Although I admittedly do not really get the meaning of `mem_stats_formatted = " ".join(mem_stats.split())`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `str.split()` and assign to variables, also a second argument with default can help you with the only total/free avail scenario

```
def get_free_memory(ssh_obj, raw=True):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_obj.exec_command('free -h')
    mem_stats = stdout.readlines()[1]

    if raw:
        mem_stats_formatted = " ".join(mem_stats.split())
        return mem_stats_formatted
    else:
        _, total, used, free, shared, cache, avail = mem_stats_formatted.split()
        return total, avail  # You may format this to a string if you wish
```

Edit:
I don't know what you do with this info but it seems more useful to me to return a dictionary of all the data and consume it later

```
def get_free_memory(ssh_obj):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_obj.exec_command('free -h')
    mem_stats = stdout.readlines()[1]
    _, total, used, free, shared, cache, avail = mem_stats_formatted.split()
    memory_info = {
                      'total': total,
                      'used': used, 
                      'free': free,
                      'shared': shared,
                      'cache': cache,
                      'available': avail
                  }

    return memory_info
```

Comment: I like your idea of returning a dictionary actually! I'm going to use this instead. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `mem_stats.split()` you get all the whitespace-separated values from the `mem_stats` string into a list.

So, if the values of interest for you are the 2nd and 4th element (considering that 'Mem:' is also part of your initial string) you can just access them from that list:

```
mem_fields = mem_stats.split()

total_mem = mem_fields[1] 
avail_mem = mem_fields[3]
```

Based on what you've said I can't see why you should do any string parsing to get the fields you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need `total` and `free` columns, you can return a tuple.

```
def get_free_memory(ssh_obj):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_obj.exec_command('free -h')
    mem_stats = stdout.readlines()[1]
    mem_stats_splitted = mem_stats.split()
    return (mem_stats_splitted[1], mem_stats_splitted[3])
```

Comment: `mem_stats_splitted[0]` is `Mem:`, which makes `total` value is `mem_stats_splitted[1]`